# Migrate angular app from neo to SAP Cloud Foundry

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-foundry

I seek a solution to switch from NEO environment to SAP Cloud Foundry. At the moment the structure of the NEO project looks like this

[image: image1]

`neo-app.json`

[image: image2]

​Could you tell me a solution for the migration?
Thank you very much, bye

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to export destination from NEO and then consume it in BAS, which is a IDE for CloudFoundry apps.

1. Firstly you go to the NEO app and export destination

[image]

2. Secondly you create project from template in SAP BAS and consuming your destination

[image]

Check [this blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/09/18/migrating-sap-ui5-standalone-apps-from-neo-to-cloud-foundry/) for more details, it describes SAPUI5 app, but it will be no difference for Angular.

All the credits for images goes to the above blog.